# unable to access selected application error in weblogic console

Tags: java, ant, weblogic

i am getting following error in weblogic.xml

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a invalid content was found starting with element context-root

code at error line

```
          <context-root>/car</context-root>
```

this is my weblogic.xml

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
           <wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
           <wls:local-path>/tar2data/feeds/bar</wls:local-path>
           <wls:url-pattern>*.csv</wls:url-pattern>
           </wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
           <context-root>/car</context-root>
          <wls:container-descriptor>
         <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>
         </wls:container-descriptor>
       </wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the node to <wls:context-root>?